block printing pdf in css
I'm trying to block webpage printing by adding following css to webpage head section:
<head>
<style type="text/css">@media print {              @page { size:auto; margin:.5rem 0; }             body { display: none !important; }             }</style>
</head>

it works for most pages except pdf like https://www.cos.edu/en-us/Access-Ability/Documents/intro%20to%20college%20student%20guide%202019.pdf, i am still able to print it after attaching my css to it. This can be quickly tested by F12->right click head node->Edit as HTML-> paste my css codes into it. Is there any way to block printing pdf?

"body { display: none !important; }" ?

The HTML document that your browser creates is a helper construct to display the PDF "inline". But that does not mean, what your browser will actually print, is that HTML document - it still prints only the PDF itself.

thank you CBroe, so is there any solution to this?

A pdf file does not take styling instructions from css. Google yourself: deactivate printing pdf - this shows ways to disable printing as well as ways to undo that. The user has the last laugh even if you try to prevent it. For a casual audience without technical know-how, maybe look into disabling printing in the pdf itself. They likely won't try to undo that.

the final answer is there is no way to do it with CSS
